# Hibernate Many to Many returning one object with a list

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

i'm very new to Hibernate, and i have the following scenario where Aluno (Student) and Disciplina (Discipline) have a many to many relationship.

I have mapped the classes as follows:

[image: Class: Aluno]

[image: Class: Disciplina]

This is my Dao implementation, i'm using this method just as an example of what i really want to know.

[image: Class: AlunoDaoImpl]

This is just a test to show how i am getting the results that i want in a inelegant way, i think

[image: Class: Test]

And this is to show the same results in join query, i don't if it will be relevant.

[image: MySql query]

What i want to know, and i'm struggling to accomplish, is that i want to create a method that returns only one Aluno with his disciplinas attribute filled with his respective disciplines, passing an id as parameter.
So that would be only one instance of Aluno.

I also have the basic getById method:

```
public Aluno getById(Integer id) {
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        return (Aluno) session.get(Aluno.class, id);
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But it doesn't return the disciplinas list filled, apparently.
I would really appreaciate any help or advice about this, maybe some good practice that i'm missing, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use one to many relationship, e.g. One student has many disciplines. I believe one to many relationship is more suitable for your condition.

Comment: I know that, but i want many to many just for training purpose. For example: i want to implement on my view, "how many students are enrolled to determined discipline ?"

Comment: In this case it would bring a Discipline with a list of students

Comment: So what you want is One student with disciplines list  or One discipline with student list?

Comment: For now i would be happy with one student with disciplines list, in one instance of Aluno